Is there a hyperreal field that leaves expressions like (-1)^ω and sin(ω) undefined?
There are a variety of posts about the fact that there are infinitely many non-isomorphic hyperreal fields, such as this one:
What is $\sin{ω}$?
One difference between these non-isomorphic fields is how the ultrafilter is defined in order to specify values of expressions in terms of infinite values, ω, such as:
(-1)^ω is equal to either +1 or -1 (or perhaps undefined?)
sin(ω) can take on any value between -1 and +1 (or perhaps undefined?)
My question is whether there is a hyperreal field that simply leaves such expressions as undefined.  For instance, since "lim x→∞ sin(x)" is not defined, it seems reasonable to leave the value of sin(ω) as undefined as well.
If it is possible to construct a hyperreal field in which certain values are left undefined, then could a hyperreal field be defined that simply mirrors the same undefined results as the field of real numbers?

I suppose it would be possible to define a hyperreal field where we write expressions such as $f(\omega)$ and set $f(\omega)=x$ if $\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow\infty}f(t)=x$, but I'm guessing there's some technicalities that aren't so simple.

@euclidub, what do you mean by $\omega$ exactly?

@MikhailKatz, thank you for asking me to be more specific.  By ω, I mean the reciprocal of the infinitessimal, ε.  Beyond that, I'm not specifying the ultrafilter that is defining this particular hyperreal field because that is my question.  However, I think that Nicholas answered the question below:   since sin(x) is defined for any real number, *sin(x) must be defined for any hyperreal number, including sin(ω).

@euclidub You keep saying "the". There is no single infinitesimal or infinite number in the hyperreals, there are infinitely many of them necessarily.

Thank you all for helping me better understand this.  I'm still learning.  :)

By definition, no.
What we mean by $\sin(\omega)$ is really ${}^*{\sin}(\omega)$ where ${}^*{\sin}$ is the nonstandard extension of $\sin : \mathbb R\to[0,1]$ to ${}^*{\sin} : {}^*\mathbb R\to{}^*[0,1]$. By definition it's domain is the entire hyperreal field, so of course it can be evaluated at $\omega\in{}^*\mathbb R$.
The fact that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sin(x)$ is undefined is equivalent to the fact that there is no standard $x\in\mathbb R$ such that ${}^*{\sin}(\omega)\approx x$ for all positive infinite $\omega\in{}^*\mathbb R$ (nor is $\sin$ increasing or decreasing).
$(-1)^{\omega}$ for $\omega\in{}^*\mathbb N$ is $1$ if $\omega$ is even and $-1$ if $\omega$ is odd. This is required by the Transfer Principle.

thank you.  This makes a lot of sense.  So, the fact that *sin(w) must be defined to be some x in the interval [-1,1] is one reason why there are infinitely many non-isomorphic hyperreal fields... because there is at least one hyperreal field for each possible value of sin(ω).  On top of that, there are at least 2 hyperreal fields because (−1)^ω can be either 1 or -1 (as well as the many other possibilities for imaginary values).  So, is there a finite list of such functions that require definition by ultrafilter (such as sin(x) and (-1)^x), or is this list of definitions infinite?

There is no special element called $\omega$ in nonstandard analysis.  In Nicholas' answer, he means any positive infinite element of ${}^*\mathbb R$.  On the other hand, there is a special element called $\omega$ in the surreal numbers.  When the OP says 'hyperreal field" they should specify what they mean!

@euclidub What GEdgar said is correct. Additionally, it does not really make any sense to say " one reason why there are infinitely many non-isomorphic hyperreal fields... because there is at least one hyperreal field for each possible value of sin(ω)."

@GEdgar, thank you for this insight.  I'm doing my best to say what I mean... but I'm relatively new to this field of study.

@NicholasTodoroff, thanks for helping me understand this. I hear you saying what I said does not make mathematical sense, and I can imagine you're right about this.  Rather, I should say, it helps me appreciate that there are infinitely many non-isomorphic hyperreal fields by seeing the specific concrete example that there is a different hyperreal field for each definition of sin(ω) as one particular real number in the interval [-1,1].  For otherwise, if there were no concrete difference between two non-isomorphic hyperreal fields, what would it even mean to say that they are not isomorphic?

@euclidub The isomorphism mentioned is an isomorphism of fields, i.e. a bijection $\phi$ such that $$\phi(x+y)=\phi(x)+\phi(y),$$$$\phi(xy)=\phi(x)\phi(y),$$$$\phi(0)=0,\quad\phi(1)=1.$$ The values that $\sin$ takes are irrelevant. Additionally, you have not defined $\omega$ in any way, so talking about the specific values of $\sin\omega$ makes no sense.
